# Composer install

Tags: laravel, composer

Я скачал проект с github. Проект на laravel. Первая команда это composer install. После у меня вылетает следующее:

```
**Deprecation warning: require.extended-bread-form-fields is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
Deprecation warning: require.voyager-themes is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name
can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a-z0-9]+)*$". Make sure you fix this as Composer 2.0 will error.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for intervention/image 2.5.1 -> satisfiable by intervention/image[2.5.1].
    - intervention/image 2.5.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for league/flysystem 1.0.66 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.66].
    - league/flysystem 1.0.66 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for sbamtr/laravel-source-encrypter 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by sbamtr/laravel-source-encrypter[1.1.0].
    - sbamtr/laravel-source-encrypter 1.1.0 requires ext-bolt * -> the requested PHP extension bolt is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - league/flysystem 1.0.66 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - tcg/voyager v1.4.1 requires league/flysystem ~1.0.41 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.66].
    - Installation request for tcg/voyager v1.4.1 -> satisfiable by tcg/voyager[v1.4.1].
  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.**
```

Я проигнорировал эти предупреждения и ввожу `php artisan key:generate` и снова вот это:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\MAMP\htdocs\KioskInfo-master/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\MAMP\htdocs\KioskInfo-master\artisan on line 18**.
```

Открываю этот файл и не знаю, что дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отредактировать свой `php.ini` файл. В нем необходимо найти

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

и привести его к виду

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

После чего перезагрузить ваш сервер. Для того, чтобы узнать где именно находиться ваш `php.ini` файл можете ввести комманду в консоле

```
php --ini
```

После чего заново обновить ваш композер

p.s Такую же операцию повторить и для других отсутствующи расширений, такие как `ext-bolt`

Comment: extension=php_fileinfo.dll вот этот файл я нашел и исправил. А вот ext-bolt его нет в php ini. Это файл можно скачать дополнительно?

Comment: попробуйте запустить композер с флагом --ignore-platform-reqs

Comment: А может быть проблем в том, что у меня composer.json php-7.2. А php ini в php7.4.1?